# How to read csv file into django project?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, read-csv

I'm using csv(txt) file to make graphs, but Django doesn't want to find it. So I can't understand, where should I create a file.

```
def get_plot():
    df = pd.read_csv('jobibi.txt', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

And the output on the web page:

```
FileNotFoundError at /analytics/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jobibi.txt'
```

[image: I tried to change the directory, but it didn't work]

Comment: Use the full path to the file.

Comment: U mean full path through the root? Like C:// ?

Comment: Yes. Full path .

Comment: server may run code with different `Current Working Directory` (which you can check with `print( os.getcwd() )`) - so it may search file in different folder. And this need `relative` or `absolute` path to file.

Comment: Where is the file with the `get_plot` function located?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the full path to the file you want to open.
It is generally considered to be a bad idea to hardcode the path of the file in the function call.

You can import the path of your project from your settings.py and go from there.

```
from *your_project_folder*.settings import BASE_DIR
```

You can navigate this path like this:

```
# move deeper into the path tree
my_deeper_path = BASE_DIR / 'my_directory'

# move out one level
my_shallower_path = BASE_DIR.parent
```

For more detailed information on how to navigate the paths in python - [pathlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

It should look something like this. Now you should be able to read your file.

```
from *your_project_folder*.settings import BASE_DIR

def get_plot():
    file_path = BASE_DIR / 'analytics_app' / 'jobibi.txt'
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

---

If your files are always in the same directory i recommend adding a dedicated variable in your settings.py

```
MY_CSV_PATH = BASE_DIR / 'my_permanent_directory/'
```

Then you only need to import MY_CSV_PATH and add the filename to it.

I hope this helped. Let me know if you are still having problems with it.